# BCS and Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, superconductivity, wick-theorem, self-energy

I am currently studying the strong coupling theory (by Eliashberg) of superconductivity, which is derived by BCS by considering self-energy diagrams and the following interaction potential

$$ V(q, i\omega_n) = \frac{V_e(q)}{\epsilon(q)} + M_\lambda\frac{D_\lambda(q, i\omega)}{\epsilon(q)}$$

where $V_e(q)$ is the Coulomb potential, $\epsilon(q)$ is the dielectric function and $D_\lambda$ is the retarded phonon propagator.

In BCS (following *Mahan, Many-Particle Physics*), we can define the following Green's Functions:

$$ \mathcal{G}_{p,\sigma}(\tau) = - \langle T c_{p,\sigma}(\tau)c^\dagger_{p,\sigma}(0)\rangle$$
$$ \mathcal{F}_{p}(\tau) = \langle T c_{-p, -}(\tau)c_{p,+}(0)\rangle$$
$$ \mathcal{F}^\dagger_{p}(\tau) = \langle T c^\dagger_{p,+}(\tau)c^\dagger_{-p,-}(0)\rangle$$

$\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}^\dagger$ are the *anomalous Green's Functions*, which are only non-zero in the superconducting state.

[image: Self-energy diagrams]

From there, by calling $S(p) \sim V(q)\mathcal{G}(p+q)$ and $W(p) \sim V(q)\mathcal{F}(p+q)$ the 1-phonon irreducible self-energy diagrams (neglecting vertex corrections), Mahan arrives to the Dyson Equations

$$ \mathcal{G}(p) = \mathcal{G}_0(p) [ 1 + S(p) \mathcal{G}(p) - W(p) \mathcal{F}^\dagger (p)] $$
$$ \mathcal{F}^\dagger(p) = \mathcal{G}_0(-p) [ W(p) \mathcal{G}(p) + S(-p) \mathcal{F}^\dagger (p)] $$

I don't understand how perturbation theory works in a theory with broken symmetry. First of all, Wick's Theorem works when taking averages over the non-interacting theory, which means that $\mathcal{G}_0$ is the usual propagator, and $\mathcal{F}_0 = 0$. But in that case, since the vertex conserves the number of particles, we cannot draw any diagram that would contribute to $\mathcal{F}$.

We could add some infinitesimal perturbation that triggers SSB without changing too much the free Hamiltonian, but then wouldn't we have a non-zero $\mathcal{F}_0$ diagram?

Comment: Where is that in Mahan?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer Chapter 10 (Superconductivity), paragraphs 10.1 (BCS) and 10.3 (Strong coupling theory). Strong coupling theory starts at p. 664 in the Third Edition